# XML parsing nested objects with attributes for Unity dialogues system purpose

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, parsing

I'm trying to build a basic dialogue system to use in Unity starting from a XML document that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
    <speech id="1">
      
        <bubble id="1" isQuestion="no">
          Hi!
        </bubble>
    
      <bubble id="2" isQuestion="no">
         It's been a while!
        </bubble>
    
      <bubble id="3" isQuestion="no">
         Have a look at my wares!
        </bubble>
    
      <bubble id="4" isQuestion="yes">
          Do you want to trade?
          <option id="1"> true </option>
          <option id="2"> false </option>
        </bubble>
      
      <bubble id="5" isQuestion="no">
        Goodbye!
      </bubble>
      
    </speech>
    <speech id="2">
     ...
   </speech>
```

The concept here is to store each line in a "bubble" node with the id attributes to locate the node in the speech and a Boolean variable to know if the bubble ask a question.

To read that I've tried something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml;

public class DialogueManager 
{
  
    public List<Speech> LoadSpeechs(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        doc.Load();
        List<Bouble> Boubles = new List<Bouble>();
        List<Bouble> Speechs = new List<Speech>();

        foreach (xmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
        {
            int id = node.Attributes[0].Value;
            foreach (xmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
            {
                int id = node.Attributes[0].Value;
                bool isQuestion = node.Attributes[1].Value;
                string content = string.Parse(node["bouble"].InnerText);

                bouble = new Bouble(id, isQuestion, value);
                Boubles.Add(bouble);
            }
            speech = new Speech(id, Boubles);
            Speechs.Add(speech);
        }
        return Speechs;
    }

    public class Speech
    {
        public int SpeechID { get; set; }

        public Speech(int m_speechID, List<Bouble> bobules)
        {
            SpeechID = m_speechID;
            Boubles = bobules;
        }
    }

    public class Bouble
    {
        public bool IsQuesion { get; set; }
        public int NodeID { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Bouble(int m_nodeID, bool m_isQuestion, string m_value)
        {
            NodeID = m_nodeID;
            IsQuesion = m_isQuestion;
            Content = m_value;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get a tons of error, which are difficult to understand alone.
So here I am. I should mention that I'm not trying to realize something in particular just learning the paradigm and Unity so I prefer some comment and explanation on how this work and where I'm mistaken rather than other ways around, but all reply will be welcome :)

I'm planning on adding more attributes, but for now I'd like to figure how to make this work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, I find the following problem and you could make some changes.

**First**, we should have the `root` node when we want to read the xml files.
Here is my tested xml:

**Second**, we need to use type convert if we want to convert one type to another type.
Such as the following code:

```
  int sid = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes[0].Value);
  string content = Lnode.InnerText;(InnerText will return a string type, there is no need to convert again)
```

**Third**, we could use the following code convert "yes" or "no" to type **bool**.

```
 text = Lnode.Attributes[1].Value.ToString();
 if(text=="yes")
 {
  isquestion = true;
 }
 else
 {
 isquestion = false;
 }
```

**Fourth**, we need to put the `Speechs.Add(speech);` to outside the inner loop.

**Finally**, you could refer to the following completed code example to convert xml to list.

Code:

```
 public class DialogueManager
    {

        public List<Speech> LoadSpeechs(XmlDocument doc)
        {
            doc.Load("test.xml");
            List<Bouble> Boubles = new List<Bouble>();
            List<Speech> Speechs = new List<Speech>();
            string text = string.Empty;
            bool isquestion = false;
            Speech speech = null;
            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (node.Name == "speech")
                {
                    int sid = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes[0].Value);
                    foreach (XmlNode Lnode in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        int bid = Convert.ToInt32(Lnode.Attributes[0].Value);
                        text = Lnode.Attributes[1].Value.ToString();
                        if(text=="yes")
                        {
                            isquestion = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isquestion = false;
                        }
                        string content = Lnode.InnerText;

                        Bouble bouble = new Bouble(bid, isquestion, content);
                        Boubles.Add(bouble);
                    }
                    speech = new Speech(sid, Boubles);

                }
           
                Speechs.Add(speech);

            }
            return Speechs;
        }

        public class Speech
        {
            public int SpeechID { get; set; }

            public List<Bouble> Boubles { get; set; }

            public Speech(int m_speechID, List<Bouble> bobules)
            {
                SpeechID = m_speechID;
                Boubles = bobules;
            }
        }

        public class Bouble
        {
            public bool IsQuesion { get; set; }
            public int NodeID { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }

            public Bouble(int m_nodeID, bool m_isQuestion, string m_value)
            {
                NodeID = m_nodeID;
                IsQuesion = m_isQuestion;
                Content = m_value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Tested code and result:**(I tested in console app)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DialogueManager manager = new DialogueManager();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            var list=manager.LoadSpeechs(doc);
            foreach (DialogueManager.Speech speech in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(speech.SpeechID);
                foreach (DialogueManager.Bouble bouble in speech.Boubles)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(bouble.NodeID);
                    Console.WriteLine(bouble.IsQuesion);
                    Console.WriteLine(bouble.Content);

                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, tried this one and with small fixes I was able to complete make it fit in my system. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Phazertron, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, If you don't mind you can click '✔' to mark my reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is one **issue** with your XML file: You need a **root element** in a form like e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <speech>
    ...
  </speech>
  <speech>
    ...
  </speech>
</Root>
```

---

Then instead of parsing this all "manually" you could/should use [`XMLSerializer`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer).

This allows you to completely flexible add more elements and attributes without having to change the parser method all the time. You rather already define the entire XML scheme structure directly in the class definitions via [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/)

and do something like e.g.

```
// In general make your classes Serializable and use fields instead of properties
// This way you can also see them in the Unity Inspector
// See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html
[Serializable]
// That generates/interprets the general XML root element
[XmlRoot]
public class Root
{
    // By matching this element name with the root name of the Speech class (see below)
    // This is treated as array without the need for an additional wrapper tag
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "speech")] public List<Speech> speeches = new List<Speech>();
}

[Serializable]
// By using the same ElementName as root for this
// It will not read/write an additional array wrapper tag but rather direct children of the Root
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "speech")]
public class Speech
{
    // Makes this an attribute without the speech tag
    // NOTE: I think you wouldn't really need these
    //       They are elements in an array so you could rely on the index itself
    [XmlAttribute] public int id;

    [XmlElement("bubble")] public List<Bubble> bubbles = new List<Bubble>();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "bubble")]
public class Bubble
{
    [XmlAttribute] public int id;
    
    // This treats the label as the actual text between the tags
    [XmlText] public string label;

    // NOTE: Here I thought your bool is quite redundant, you don't need it
    // simply check if there are options elements -> if so it is automatically a question
    // if there are no options anyway -> there is no question
    public bool isQuestion => options.Count != 0;

    // If there are none in your XML file the list will simply stay empty
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "option")] public List<Option> options = new List<Option>();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "option")]
public class Option
{
    [XmlAttribute] public int id;

    [XmlText] public string label;

    // Optionally you could use some return value like a bool or enum
    // but again, you can also simply go by index
}
```

This requires your XML file be slightly changed and look like e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <speech id="1">
    <bubble id="1">Hallo</bubble>
    
    <bubble id="2">World?
      <option id="1">Yes</option>
      <option id="2">Nope</option>
    </bubble>
  </speech>
  
  <speech id="2">
    <bubble id="1">Hi</bubble>
    <bubble id="2">There!</bubble>
  </speech>
</Root>
```

Then finally you can simply have two methods like e.g.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Input")]
    [Tooltip("The FULL path to your file - for the example below I cheated ;) ")] 
    public string xmlFileUrl = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Example.xml");

    [Header("Result")] 
    [Tooltip("The deserialized c# classes")]
    public Root root;

    // This allows you to call this method via the Inspector Context Menu
    [ContextMenu(nameof(LoadFile))]
    public void LoadFile()
    {
        // Open the file as a stream
        using (var stream = File.Open(xmlFileUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            // create an XMLSerializer according to the root type
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

            // Deserialize the file according to your implemented Root class structure
            root = (Root) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    [ContextMenu(nameof(WriteFile))]
    public void WriteFile()
    {
        // Delete the existing file
        if (File.Exists(xmlFileUrl)) File.Delete(xmlFileUrl);

        // create the StreamingAsset folder if not exists
        // NOTE: Later in your app you want to use the StreamingAssets only 
        //       if your file shall be read-only!
        //       otherwise use persistentDataPath
        if(!Directory.Exists(Application.streamingAssetsPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.streamingAssetsPath);

        // Create a new file as stream
        using (var stream = File.Open(xmlFileUrl, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

            // serialize the current Root class into the XML file
            serializer.Serialize(stream, root);
        }

#if UNITY_EDITOR 
        // in the editor refresh the AssetDataBase of Unity 
        // so you see the added files in the Project View
        UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.Refresh();
#endif
    }
}
```

[image]

And now you have access to the `root` and all its properties directly like e.g.

```
var isQuestion = root.speeches[0].bubbles[1].isQuestion;
```

and you can do the entire preparation and editing also directly via the Inspector in Unity.

---

Then as a final little personal touch I would rather use

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = nameof(Speech))] public List<Speech> speeches = new List<Speech>();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = nameof(Speech))]
public class Speech
{
    ...

    [XmlElement(nameof(Bubble))] public List<Bubble> bubbles = new List<Bubble>();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = nameof(Bubble))]
public class Bubble
{
    ...
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName = nameof(Option))] public List<Option> options = new List<Option>();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = nameof(Option))]
public class Option
{
    ...
}
```

and in the XML use the uppercase class names

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Speech id="1">
    <Bubble id="1">Hallo</Bubble>
    
    <Bubble id="2">World?
      <Option id="1">Yes</Option>
      <Option id="2">Nope</Option>
    </Bubble>
  </Speech>
  
  <Speech id="2">
    <Bubble id="1">Hi</Bubble>
    <Bubble id="2">There!</Bubble>
  </Speech>
</Root>
```

Comment: Give me some time sto study this because you are using attributes that i don't know yet. As soon as I've understand this I'll let you know. So far thank you very much!